# If I edit an object in a list created with ToList in EF 6 will SaveChanges persist edits to data store

Tags: entity-framework

I'm a bit confused about how to use the lists returned from a ToList in EF6. If I bind the list to a CollectionViewSource I can easily view the objects returned. However, I consider these objects somewhat disconnected from the data that EF tracks in memory such that if I edit the objects in the list and then call SaveChanges, the edits won't be persisted back to the data store. For that reason, I have been binding to the DBSets .Local, making edits to these objects, and then calling SaveChanges.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those objects are not disconnected at all! Every modification you do to their properties will be persisted to the data store on a SaveChanges call.

Entity Framework works in such a manner that it loads one record once, and only once into one context. In other words, if you obtain an entity (say, through a Linq query) from the DbSet object, it will also  appear in the Local collection, and it will be the very same object. Same thing applies to the results of ToList() functions; there is only one instance for one record in a context. At this point, i'm sure you say my first statement is evident.

Btw, your method (consequently) does the work as well.

Regards

Comment: So, after trying it myself, I see that this is the case. When I look at the list, it contains the actual objects, not references to objects in the .Local store. I believe that the context loads an entity only once but am left confused that the documentation states ToList creates a "copy" of the entities. So, I'm still puzzled how the copies in the list are linked to the entities in the context.

Comment: And, when I create a list from ToList, how is it a part of the context? It's just a list property that I created. How is the Context "aware" of it. If I execute ToList, does .Local contain the actual entities or references to the list I just filled (ie loading an entity once and only once)

Comment: The list itself is not a part of the context, it will not affect the DbSet (i mean it does not count as a modification) if you add or remove elements from the list, but the elements of the list are. 
Because entites are reference types (they are instances of classes, not structs), neither Local, nor the list contains actual entities, both contain references. But if both have the "same" entity in it (i mean entity with the same primary key in both), those are references to the same object, if you change one, the other will also exhibit the change. - Is it an understandable/satisfying answer?

Comment: Could you please post the link of the doc you've read? I'm not sure what they mean by "copy", but i'm pretty sure it does not mean "clone".

Comment: perfectly understandable explanation. Both are references. Additions/Deletions need to be done to the DBSet for SaveChanges to work (and then recreate list with ToList I guess). Here is the reference I was referring to. Now however it makes sense: For example, ToList can be called on a query to copy the results into a new List < T>. Calling a method such as this will cause all the results to be retrieved from the database and be copied into the new List < T>.

Lerman, Julia; Miller, Rowan (2012-02-23). Programming Entity Framework: DbContext (p. 19). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.